# Update Trigger is updating multiple records instead of single record

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, sql-update

I'm new to triggers, facing an issue during update trigger.
Scenario:
I have two tables [table1 and table2] when a particular column changes in table1, I need to update the table2 records based on few conditions

Here is my trigger,

```
create or replace TRIGGER UPDATE_TABLE1 
BEFORE UPDATE OF LOWTHRESHOLD, HIGHTHRESHOLD ON TABLE1 
for each row
  when(nvl(old.LOWTHRESHOLD,0) <> nvl(new.LOWTHRESHOLD,0) 
  OR  nvl(old.HIGHTHRESHOLD,0) <> nvl(new.HIGHTHRESHOLD,0))
  declare
  PID number(3) := nvl(:old.PID,0);
  oldLOWTH number(2) := nvl(:old.LOWTHRESHOLD,0);
  oldHIGHTH number(2) := nvl(:old.HIGHTHRESHOLD,0);
  newLOWTH number(2) := nvl(:new.LOWTHRESHOLD,0);
  newHIGHTH number(2) := nvl(:new.HIGHTHRESHOLD,0);
  ratio DOUBLE PRECISION;
  oldTHCrossed number(1) := 0;
  objID number(10) := 0;
  objType number(1) := 0;
   CURSOR profileUtil_Cursor  IS
        SELECT * FROM TABLE2 where upid = PID; 
  begin
    
  dbms_output.enable(1000);
 
  FOR v_record in profileUtil_Cursor LOOP
  ratio := v_record.UTILIZATIONRATIO;
  oldTHCrossed := v_record.THCROSSED;
  objID := v_record.objID;
  objType := v_record.objType;
 IF(ratio < newLOWTH AND ratio < newHIGHTH ) THEN
  UPDATE TABLE2 SET THCROSSED = 1, LASTUPDATED = date_to_miniseconds(sysdate) 
  WHERE objID = objID and objType = objType and upid = PID;
  ELSIF(newLOWTH <= ratio AND ratio <= newHIGHTH) THEN 
    UPDATE TABLE2 SET THCROSSED = 2, LASTUPDATED = date_to_miniseconds(sysdate) 
    WHERE objID = objID and objType = objType and upid = PID; 
  ELSIF(ratio > newHIGHTH) THEN
    UPDATE TABLE2 SET THCROSSED = 3, LASTUPDATED = date_to_miniseconds(sysdate)
    WHERE upid = PID and objID = objID and objType = objType; 
  END IF;
  END LOOP;
    IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('NOT FOUND');
    END IF;
END;
```

But when this trigger is executed, all the records in TABLE2 are getting updated.
Please provide some pointers to solve this issue.

Comment: Do not use the same variable names as column names. Because then you cannot tell, what is variable and what is table column. Currently I can assume that `WHERE objID = objID and objType = objType` is constant true unless some of the columns have `null` values. Apart from the above issue you may use `merge` statement and `case` expression for calculation of `THCROSSED` to update target table without imperative logic.

Comment: It looks as though the three updates are the same apart from the value of `thcrossed`. I would have that as a variable, set it to 1, 2, or 3 according to your logic, then have one update. Also, formatting code with a little care makes it a lot easier to work on and spot issues.

Comment: Also, `IF SQL%NOTFOUND` will never be true, because the only SQL is part of a cursor FOR loop.

Comment: The issue was because variable names were the same as column names as highlighted by @astentx.
After correcting, the update works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cursor selects all rows whose `UPID = :OLD.PID`. According to what you said, all rows in `table2` have the same `upid` column value, and it is equal to `table1.pid` which is being updated *right now*.

`UPDATE` statements will modify rows that satisfy their `WHERE` conditions. All 3 of them are the same:

```
      WHERE     objID = objID         --> that's 0
            AND objType = objType     --> that's 0 as well
            AND upid = PID            --> that's "old" table1.pid
```

which - additionally to my 1st statement - means that all rows in `table2` not only share the same `upid`, but their `objID` and `objType` column values are `0` (at least, that's what you declared).

Furthermore (as @astentx nicely observed), if you name variables the same as column names, it behaves as if you put `where 1 = 1` which is always true. Use prefix for local variables, e.g. `l_` so `where` clause would turn into

```
      WHERE     objID   = l_objID       --> that's 0
            AND objType = l_objType     --> that's 0 as well
            AND upid    = l_PID         --> that's "old" table1.pid
```

So: if everything above is true, then yes - trigger will update all rows in `table2`.